# Mysql Groupby, order not returning individual sums

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
     $SQL = "SELECT pumpSales._end_date, SUM(pumpSales.AMOUNT) as       
     totalAmount, payments_data.USER
     FROM
     payments_data INNER JOIN pumpSales ON payments_data.Pay_sale_id =   
     pumpSales._sale_id 

     WHERE 
     pumpSales._end_date =CURDATE();

     GROUP BY
     payments_data.USER 

     ORDER BY
     pumpSales._end_date ASC LIMIT 3";
```

The result I want is
The users with their individual total amounts
Starting with the highest for the day

But
What I get is the name of one user with total amount for all the users
e.g

2018-01-11   user 1      400,000

where 400,000 is the total for user1, user2, user3

Comment: You have an extra `;` after the `where` clause, therefore the `group by` is not in the query.

Comment: Your have three output columns, one of them combined by the `SUM` and a second through the `GROUP BY`. Hence, you have to do something with the third column (`payments_data.USER` in your case).

Comment: @Shadow that's it! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have USER in the ORDER BY clauses, and you don't have _end_date in the GROUP BY clause. Consider:

```
 SELECT pumpSales._end_date, 
   SUM(pumpSales.AMOUNT) as totalAmount, 
   payments_data.USER
 FROM
   payments_data 
 INNER JOIN pumpSales 
   ON payments_data.Pay_sale_id = pumpSales._sale_id 
 WHERE 
   pumpSales._end_date =CURDATE();
 GROUP BY
   payments_data.USER, pumpsales._end_date 
 ORDER BY
   payments_data.USER, pumpSales._end_date";
```

It is also not clear what the LIMIT in your query is intended to do.